# why would akamai change browser security behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, cors

In one environment we have a x-domain jquery ajax request with method GET. Nothing fancy.

```
              jQuery.ajax({
                    type:     'GET',                  
                    url:      url,
                    contentType:'text/plain',
                    xhrFields: {
                       withCredentials: true
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                       //stuffff   
                    }
                });
```

Works fine when served from tomcat or apache. The GET stays a GET, it does not get preflighted to OPTIONS

```
GET https://qa.example.com HTTP/1.1
Host: somehost.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: */*
Origin: http://example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain
DNT: 1
Referer: http://example.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,sr;q=0.6
Cookie: JSESSIONID=xxx
```

But then when the static files are hosted on Akamai (in a different environment), the request gets preflighted to OPTIONS using the same exact JS.

```
OPTIONS https://stage.example.com HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Origin: https://someorigin.example.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type, accept
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Host: test-me.example.com
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

**What on earth would make the browser treat this x-domain request's security differently just because it is hosted on a CDN?** (we do custom DNS to the Akamai files, so they look as if coming from our domain). Also, note that the server in this situation is not allowing OPTIONS and we don't have access, but it should not matter for simple GETS without data, per these rules:

```
Simple requests are requests that meet the following criteria:

•   HTTP Method matches (case-sensitive) one of:
       HEAD
       GET
       POST
• HTTP Headers matches (case-insensitive):
       Accept
       Accept-Language
       Content-Language
       Last-Event-ID
       Content-Type, but only if the value is one of:
         •  application/x-www-form-urlencoded
         •  multipart/form-data
         •  text/plain
```

This happens regardless of browser, Chrome, IE, FF for simple GET requests.

Comment: did you have any luck with this?

Comment: nope. heh, don't even work there anymore (unrelated to this).